# Flutter Image Picker problem on iOS, pop-up with "Select more photos" even if I want to select only one, the image is not added

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, imagepicker

I am using *Image Picker* to select an image from the gallery. When I don't have any images uploaded, after I add one image, this pop-up is appearing as shown below.
[image]

If I press "Select More Photos...", the image or images are not added after selection. How to get rid of this pop-up or what do I need to change in my code to be able to *Select More Photos* if he wants. I read that *Image Picker* is unable to handle picking multiple images once, and I don't need that necessarily, so I need to get rid of this pop-up, because even if I select only one image from "Select more photos...", it is not added.

```
 void _openCameraAndAddPossibleImage(String? cleverClosetOrganizer, String cameraOrGallery, int isMyClosetCheck) async{
    try{
      var pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source: cameraOrGallery == 'camera' ? ImageSource.camera : ImageSource.gallery,
      );
      if (pickedFile != null) {
        var imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
        Uint8List imageRaw = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
        String newImage = CleverCloset.base64String(imageRaw);
        if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          if(isMyClosetCheck==1) {
            CleverCloset cleverClosetToAdd = CleverCloset(closetOrganizer: cleverClosetOrganizer, isMyCloset: isMyClosetCheck, image: newImage);
            addImageOnClosetOrganizer(cleverClosetToAdd);
          }
          else {
            CleverCloset cleverClosetToAdd = CleverCloset(isMyCloset: isMyClosetCheck, image: newImage);
            addImageOnToBuy(cleverClosetToAdd);
          }
        });

        }
      }
    }
   catch (e){
      return ;
   }

  }
```

[image]

Comment: Post your crash log here.

Comment: Actually you have to choose `"keep current selection"` since it's just one picture.

Comment: Yes, I have to choose "keep current selection", but the pop-up should not exist. I will post the crash log immediately.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the question, because I don't have any error log, the images are not added, and that's all, if I press "Select more photos...". I will add a Gif workaround.

Comment: I have used the package before and it worked the same way. I think it's just the way it works. You go to `Gallery`, choose a picture and the pop-up appears then you have to choose `"keep current selection"`(probably is like an `OK` button to confirm your selection).

Comment: did you find nay solutions @RolandIordache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this discussion https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65995, I find out that it's a common bug on iOS.

I solved this issue by adding:

```
 image_picker:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/cpboyd/plugins.git
      ref: ios-no-permissions
      path: packages/image_picker/image_picker
```

Using this branch, it will remove the pop-up.

Comment: not working, I want to remove the select photos options

Comment: Hi @MRShubhamvyas would you able to remove "select photos" option from the pop-up?

Answer (score 3):

Please try passing `requestFullMetadata: false` to pickImage function:

```
ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera, requestFullMetadata: false);
```

As per docs:

> If requestFullMetadata is set to true, the plugin tries to get the
> full image metadata which may require extra permission requests on
> some platforms, such as Photo Library Usage permission on iOS.